# Is it better to use String.valueOf() or .toString()

Tags: java

Is it more expensive to use String.valueOf("*/any non-String value*/") or to use non-String-value.toString()?

I am asking in the context of wanting to insert non-String values in a String.format statement:

```
Html.fromHtml(String.format("<b> %s </b>", value.toString or String.valueOf(value))) ?
```

As I want my code to be as efficient as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry about it. It has nothing to do with efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

value.toString() but in full honesty the are doing the same thing.  Can return a null pointer exception though